# re-use same session for each httpclient request

Tags: java, servlets, httpwebrequest

My java servlet call httpclient to get page content. may I know what is the best practice to re-use same session for same user when doing multiple sub sequence request from servlet

Comment: You mean, you will be using a Java HTTPClient to make the requests to another server, and you want to keep the session of the other server?

Comment: ya keep it for subsequence call later

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your are using Apache's [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

[Here's the information](http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-httpclient/ForAbsoluteBeginners#head-1cf332662ef015b4aa19e06dc24c24e391ecda69) you're probably looking for